# How to interpret this confusion matrix and roc curve?

Tags: r, roc, auc, confusion-matrix

I got these two images for evaluating a RF:

[image: img]

[image: img2]

I wonder why the ROC curve seems to be so good while the confusion matrix shows that the True Positive isn't so good with only ~16 %?
By looking only at the ROC curve it looks like quite a good model while the TP states otherwise, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The True positive is the bottom right cell in the confusion matrix.

Find more [here](https://www.dataschool.io/simple-guide-to-confusion-matrix-terminology/#:%7E:text=A%20confusion%20matrix%20is%20a,related%20terminology%20can%20be%20confusing.)

Comment: thanks, was looking at wrong confusion tables, then..